# Error: Retrieving the file name for a component failed with error code 0x03B98F74

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

I have simple SSIS ActiveX Script task that is returning with the above error when executing:

I've cut all the code down to just an empty function:

```
function main
end function
```

And have ensured the EntryMethod property of the component is **main**

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I came across this same error and found that a connection in the activex script was referencing a dsn name that didn't exist.  I added the DSN through control panel -> administrative tools -> Data sources (ODBC) and the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

This useful error will be thrown for ANY error in an ActiveX script task (although the error code will vary). In my particular circumstance it only occurred when running under the 64 bit DTEXEC process which made it convoluted to track down.  Hopefully of some use to anyone supporting ancient tech.